# Debugging IE11 on Mac

Tags: macos, internet-explorer-11

This may already have a question somewhere, but I am at a loss as to how to debug IE11 on my Mac.

I currently run a full Win10 instance in a Virtual Box, but it is so bloated that it is nearly impossible to move nimbly between coding and debugging. IE dev-tools are also inaccessible using this method because it just cripples the VM, so I am flying blind with coding.

I have looked up tutorials as to how to run IE on a Mac direct using Wine/Remote Desktop, but these instructions are out of date or the supporting software does not work as intended. Also, Microsoft (being the evil empire that they are) discontinued support for debugging with Azure so that is another option off the table.

If there is anything that actually works without having to shell out $$$ please let me know as it is so painful currently to debug the worst browser that will never die.

Answer (score -1):

From your description, I can see that you had already try to use the Windows 10 VM but it get hangs.

You can try to go to **Windows Features on or off** inside **Control Panel-> Programs-> Programs and Features** and try to turn off the features that you are not using may help to reduce the load.

It is possible that you are running your VM in a very less memory that downs the performance of the OS.

If possible for you than try to install a VM with some more memory.

Otherwise you can try to install Windows 7 in your VM and upgrade to IE 11 in that.

It can help you to solve your issue with the OS and you can debug the code on IE 11.

Below are some helpful references that may give you some additional information.

[How to test your website with Internet Explorer on a Mac](https://www.pluralsight.com/blog/tutorials/remoteie-on-macs)

[How to Debug in IE on a Mac](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/363676/How-to-Debug-in-IE-on-a-Mac)